# Trying to convert a string to a list of complex numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a string to a list of complex numbers. (If you were to read it without quotes, it would be a list of complex numbers.) I've written a function to do this, but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "complex.py", line 26, in <module>
        print(listCmplx('[1.111 + 2.222j, 3.333 + 4.444j]'))
    File "complex.py", line 10, in listCmplx
        while (not isDigit(listIn[count])) and (listIn[count] != '.'):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
def isDigit(char):
    return char in '0123456789'

def listCmplx(listIn):
    listOut = []
    count = 0
    real = '0'
    imag = '0'
    while count < len(listIn):
        while (not isDigit(listIn[count])) and (listIn[count] != '.'):
            count += 1
        start = count
        while (isDigit(listIn[count])) or (listIn[count] == '.'):
            count += 1
        end = count
        if listIn[count] == 'j':
            imag = listIn[start:end]
        else:
            real = listIn[start:end]
        if listIn[count] == ',':
            listOut += [float(real) + float(imag) * 1j]
            real = '0'
            imag = '0'
    return listOut

print(listCmplx('[1.111 + 2.222j, 3.333 + 4.444j]'))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the string.

Comment: Your inner `while` loops don't check for getting to the end of the string.

Comment: Here it is: '[1.111 + 2.222j, 3.333 + 4.444j]' (This string is just a test to see if my function works.)

Comment: should 2.222j be a float or str?

Comment: It is part of the string that I commented on this post, but I want to convert it to the imaginary component of one of the items of the variable listOut.

Comment: I know, when the function returns the list, will it be a str?

Comment: just to avoid any confusion can you enhance your question such with two lines, like for example:

`mylist_in=......` and then the call to your function `listCmplx(mylist_in)`

This allows to copy paste your **exact** example and see whether we get the same error messages as you. It also gets rid of some ambiguity.

You talk about `lists` and `strings` which is which and which is used where.

A complete reproducable example is worth more than 100 words

Comment: `while (not isDigit(listIn[count])) and (listIn[count] != '.'):` will evaluate to `True` at `]` (the end of the string) in your example of  `[1.111 + 2.222j, 3.333 + 4.444j]`.

Then count will be incremented past the size of `listIn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazingly, this is something Python can do without needing any functions written, with its inbuilt complex number class.

```
listIn = '1.111 + 2.222j, 3.333 + 4.444j'
listOut =  eval(listIn)

print(listOut[0])
print(listOut[0].imag,listOut[0].real)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If the input is untrusted, use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead. In fact, it's probably best practice to avoid `eval` at all costs in any case.

Comment: Just tested it and I can confirm that `literal_eval` supports complex number expressions.

Comment: @LoganTischler The point here is that if the string might derive from third-party input, a maliciously constructed string could cause `eval` to execute code that should not be.

Comment: @Logan I'm not saying it doesn't work, I'm saying, if you don't trust the input you're receiving, [using `eval` is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your original parsing problem is a good example because it highlights the importance, whenever possible, of using the simplest, highest-level parsing tools available. Simple, high-level tools include basic things like splitting, stripping, and string indexing. Regex might be considered a mid-level tool, and it's certainly a more complex one. The lowest-level tool -- and the one you chose -- was character by character analysis. Never do that unless you are absolutely forced to by the problem at hand.

Here's one way to parse your example input with simple tools:

```
# Helper function to take a string a return a complex number.
def s2complex(s):
    r, _, i = s.split()
    return complex(float(r), float(i[:-1]))

# Parse the input.
raw = '[1.111 + 2.222j, 3.333 + 4.444j]'
xs = raw[1:-1].split(', ')
nums = [s2complex(x) for x in xs]

# Check.
for n in nums:
    print(n)
```